# maven versions:update-properties with version rules and current version greater

Tags: java, maven, plugins, build, version

If my current property in pom is having value `3.2.4-SNAPSHOT` and my `maven-version-rules.xml` has the following code:

```
<ruleset xmlns="http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/rule/2.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/rule/2.0.0
     http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/xsd/rule-2.0.0.xsd">
    <rules>
        <rule groupId="com.my.example" artifactId="*">
            <ignoreVersions>
                <ignoreVersion type="regex">[2456789]\..*</ignoreVersion>
                <ignoreVersion type="regex">[3].[1-9]\..*</ignoreVersion>
            </ignoreVersions>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</ruleset>
```

It is clear that the current version violates this rule. The only version patterns possible here is something like `3.0.x-SNAPSHOT`

but when I run

```
mvn versions:update-properties versions:commit -DallowSnapshots=true
```

the version remains unchanged. I think this is because the current version is greater than the versions that pass the rules.

My question is:

Is there a way to tell maven to validate the current value and override it even if it is greater than the possible values but does not pass the rules?

Comment: Is the usage of the rules file really needed? Can you show your pom version? And on which versions you have? May be you can use `allowMinorUpgrade=false`?

Comment: it cant be done with the `allowMinorUpgrade=false` as then it depends totally on the current value, but I want to override the current value based on the rules!

Comment: what do you mean by `depends totally on the current value..`. A version contains `Major.Minor.Patch...` So to be honest I don't see the issue here?

Comment: the rules allow me to define specific rules for valid versions, so even if the version is updated by a user mistakenly, the rules can define a way of marking that version as invalid(this doesn't happen right now and I am hoping to find some way of doing this)